# Updating parameters of neural network manually in PyTorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

Let's say I have a neural network N where after training it, I want to manually update its parameters. For example, I would like to zero out elements of its N.parameters() which their absolute value is less than some threshold. How can I do that?
If I do

```
N.parameters()
```

It gives me a generator which I cannot iterate over its elements. Is there any easier way to access the parameters in PyTorch?

Comment: What do you mean you can't iterate over the elements ? That's what generators are for.

Comment: Can you write that form for me? I really do not know the command to iterate through the elements N.parameter(). In general, can you write the command that let me iterate through the tensor in pytorch?

Comment: It's simply `for param in N.parameters():`. In the loop `param` will represent each parameter you iterate through.